# FileNotFoundException, but catch block is not entered (Async method)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, uwp

I have a method in which I'm checking if a file exists in my filesystem (UWP):

```
private async Task<bool> FileExistsAsync(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filename != null)
            {
                var item = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename); // FileNotFoundException happens here
                if (item != null)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) // I Expect the debugger to handle the FileNotFoundException here, but it never happens
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to get a non-existing file with `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync`, I get an exception. For some reason it's not handled by my catch block, but looks like this instead:

[image]

**What I've tried**:

- Explicitly handle a `FileNotFoundException`
- Add a Try-catch-block inside of the if-statement

Note that the method needs to stay asynchronous because I have other stuff going on in this method which I removed in order to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Why is the debugger not entering my catch block when a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown?

Comment: try this. catch (Exception ) 
        {
            return false;
        }

Comment: @vivek It didn't change anything. Also, I need the parameter in my code (as I said, I removed some unnecessary parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Exception Popup i see `[x] Break when this exception type is thrown`. Try disabling it there, or from the Exception Settings dialog (Ctrl-Alt-E on my system, or menu Debug > Windows > Exception Settings).

Comment: Thank you, that what causing my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var item = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
```

Did you have try and catch in this function ?? if yes, add

```
throw
```

in catch

try this :[Why can't I catch an exception from async code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865523/why-cant-i-catch-an-exception-from-async-code)
and this : [Catch an exception thrown by an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method..hope) can help you.

Comment: I can't change the code of `GetFileFromPathAsync` because it's from the `Windows.Storage` namespace.