# HttpClient.SendAsync() Exception

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

I cannot seem to catch [HttpRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception?view=netstandard-2.0) or any exception for that matter when sending request to a nonexistent endpoint.

http://localhost:8030/ does not exist, however I should be able to catch [HttpRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception?view=netstandard-2.0) in try/catch block. What am I missing ?

```cs
            Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8030/");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var rm = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = address
            };

            try
            {
                var response = await client.SendAsync(rm);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
```

[VSscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAbP8.png)

Comment: Does it "catch" your exception if you run it outside the debugger?

Comment: This is being caught, however, you are seeing a debugging feature. If you press continue you will likely see it hit the catch

Comment: In the Debug > Exceptions dialog, click Add, select Common Language Runtime exceptions, and enter the full name of the exception. Then uncheck the Thrown checkbox for this exception.

Comment: @mxmissile It worked thank you, but how is this a feature ? Why is it behaving differently ?

Comment: Disable "Just My Code" in your debugger settings, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865523/why-cant-i-catch-an-exception-from-async-code

Comment: Because, the designers thought by default some exceptions might be useful to know at runtime in debug, so you can inspect variables and state before the stack completely unwinds. You can switch this off multiple ways, its as easy as that

Comment: You can also change it directly in the exception dialog "Break when this exception type is thrown"